# Spotify developer search

Tags: spotify

I am confused about how the search function works in the Spotify API.  Their example is like this:

```
    var sp = getSpotifyApi();
    var models = sp.require('$api/models');

    var search = new models.Search('Rihanna');
    search.localResults = models.LOCALSEARCHRESULTS.APPEND;

    var searchHTML = document.getElementById('results');

    search.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function() {
        var results = search.tracks;
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
            var link = document.createElement('li');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = results[i].uri;
            link.appendChild(a);
            a.innerHTML = results[i].name;
            fragment.appendChild(link);
        }

        searchHTML.appendChild(fragment);
    });

    search.appendNext();
```

So, I guess that calling appendNext() initiates the search, and the inner function is called when it has results?  But the results are limited to a certain number (default 50) of the total.  How do you get the rest?  Do you call appendNext() again recursively from inside the callback?  Also, does that mean that after you do that, your list includes the original results, or are the original results replaced?  Anyone know of an example that searches through *all* available results?

Also they mention that if the search is running, appendNext() does nothing.  So how do you gracefully wait until the current search is complete before getting the next 'page'?

Their documentation is terrible, IMHO.  Say you have 1000 search results total from the server.  And say I want to see results 900-1000.  Have I got to keep calling AppendNext over and over until I get to 900?

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 0):

There is no pagination when using the Search functionality built in the Spotify Apps API. You can increase the number of results so it returns more than 50 results (see [the Search page in the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/833e3a06d6.html)), although the amount is limited (it seems to be 200 tracks at the moment).

There is an alternative way, which is performing requests to the [Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/search/) instead.

Comment: Wait so you are saying there is no way to get a complete set of search results using their API?  So if I want to search for all Rhianna songs, like their example, I can only get 200 and if the song I am looking for isn't in the first 200, I am out of luck?  That is ridiculous! What is the AppendNext call used for then?